# Why DispatchGroup is not working correctly

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatchgroup

I want the function to wait for the 1st function to get the data from the firebase first then execute the 2nd one but it turn out that it is not working in a correct order

```
func getMenuData(){
    getMenu()
    getIngredient()
    getRecipe()
    self.dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main){
        print("finished download")
    }
}
func getMenu(){
    self.dispatchGroup.enter()
      let menu = self.ref.collection("menu").document("menu1")
      menu.getDocument(source: .cache) { (document, error) in
           if let document = document {
              let menuName = document.get("menuEngName") as! String
              print("MenuName = \(menuName)")

           } else {
               print("Document does not exist in cache")
           }
       }
    self.dispatchGroup.leave()
}
func getIngredient(){
    for n in 1...5 {
       print("getIngre")
    }
}
func getRecipe(){
    for n in 1...5 {
       print("getRecipe")
    }
}
```

It turn out that "finished download" has been print before the MenuName

[the result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eit6T.png)

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `leave` line must be **inside** the completion closure

```
func getMenu() {
    self.dispatchGroup.enter()
    let menu = self.ref.collection("menu").document("menu1")
    menu.getDocument(source: .cache) { (document, error) in
        if let document = document {
           let menuName = document.get("menuEngName") as! String
           print("MenuName = \(menuName)")
        } else {
           print("Document does not exist in cache")
        }
        self.dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}
```